# How do I change the color of the site loading spinner / circle in the new Chrome 77?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome 77 contains a cool new spinner loading thinger that goes on top of the favicon.  Is there any way, using CSS or otherwise, to change the color of that spinner?

I'm not sure it's the same color for all sites, but it's hard to tell.  I'd love it if it matched one of the colors in our favicon rather than just being a mix of all of them.

[image]

Comment: Doubtful...it's brower object not a HTML/CSS issue

Comment: Yeah, my hopes aren't high, but it would be great if I could do it.  I agree it probably wouldn't happen through CSS but probably through a `<link` tag in the head block or something.